# Ling to XML difference between NF 3.5 AND 4.0

Tags: linq-to-xml

```
/*  @"C:\xml\xml2.xml"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<food>
<fruits>
<fruit>Apple</fruit>
<fruit>Orange</fruit>
<fruit>Melon</fruit>
<fruit>Watermelon</fruit>
</fruits>
</food>


string xml_path2 = @"C:\xml\xml2.xml";
            XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(xml_path2);
            var qry2 = doc2.Descendants("fruits").Select(n => n.Element("fruit").Value);
            foreach (var item in qry2) {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
```

Output: Show only Apple, instead of showing all fruits

I am using Visula Studio 2008 and Net FrameWork 3.5 . Why does it shows like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  doc2.Descendants("fruits").Select(n => n.Element("fruit").Value);
> ```

This will find a single `<fruits>` element, it then applies the `Element(name)` method to it. 
[`XContainer.Element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) is defined (my emphasis):

> Gets the ***first*** (in document order) child element with the specified XName.

So you get just one result.